# Group unit tests and run only a set

Tags: scala, unit-testing, specs2

I want to have an additional battery of tests to run against a database in addition to the unit test battery that requires no IO. What's the best way to do this with specs2 and sbt?

Answer (score 3):

One of the solutions would be to put them in a namespace and use `sbt test-only` command:

```
$ sbt
> test-only com.example.utils.*
```

There's also a notion of [tags in Specs2](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.HowTo.html#Tag+examples), which could be used to include or exclude tests at run time via [SBT configuration](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#Via+SBT).